# How to generate Certificate Signing Request by windows API?

Tags: windows

How to use C++ to generate Certificate Signing Request by windows API?

I want to generate csr and send it to the server to sign it.
But I can't find the API.
Does anyone have some suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried running `makecert.exe` through [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)? In the profile menu (IIRC) you can launch makecert an see what DLL it loads and what function it calls in  them. The less .NET there is, the better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library looks to be: CertEnroll.dll
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374863%28VS.85%29.aspx

[These samples shows hot to access them from C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is where your application should go for the CSR.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me so much! I try that and found that use Xenroll in Windows XP and use certenroll in Windows7.